# Is there a way to privately send ether?

Tags: ether, privacy, zksnark

Is there currently any way to privately send ether? If not, are there any plans in the future to implement any privacy features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sending and receiving addresses and the amount are available for anyone to view. ([EtherScan](https://etherscan.io/) for reference). In the future, Ethereum does plan to implement privacy features - zero knowledge proofs to allow for private transactions. See [here](https://www.coindesk.com/zokrates-seeks-bring-best-zcash-ethereum-devcon-debut/). Also, Ethereum's plans for [plasma](https://plasma.io/) would also extend privacy to parent chains off the root chain.

Answer (score 1):

There are zk-SNARK related precompiled contracts that have been included since Byzantium in October, but AFAIK there is no user-friendly GUI for sending ZK transactions e.g. with MyEtherWallet.

https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf#subsection.E.1