# Is there any way to fund a new account privately via a randomising pool?

Tags: accounts, privacy, hd-wallets, anonymity

It isn't currently possible to create a new HD wallet account and privately fund it, is it?

I'm aware of this [thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37593/is-there-a-way-to-privately-send-ether), but I'm not asking about SNARKs. Instead, I'm curious if there's any way to send funds to a smart contract or service which subsequently funds the new account anonymously? Not sure if this would require some sort of randomness beacon similar to Dfinity's.

Centralised exchanges make this possible as a non-intended byproduct, but there's an overhead cost in signing up and paying for withdrawal fees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do exactly this with ZKSnarks but the overhead would be that you would have to actually remember/track a certain amount of information.

By privately fund it, I take it, making private the amount being funded is enough.

[This Link here](https://media.consensys.net/introduction-to-zksnarks-with-examples-3283b554fc3b) provides an example of implementing ZKSnarks to send a private transaction. The steps taken are:

1. Have the the requisite functions for it to be implemented, namely the Generator, Prover and Verifier.
2. Generate, the prover and verifier keys for each account(carefully disposing the secret used here).
3. Running the Verifier code on-chain to verify that the transaction is indeed valid.

---

An alternative is [Tumbling as shown in this thread.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2699/is-there-any-ether-mixer-tumbler-available)

Answer (score 2):

The only practical possibility to pass trough a serious forensic investigation on blockchain without revealing where are funds coming and going is by means of a off-chain server. I mean on Ethereum blockchain.

The zSNARKs are too complex to be practically implemented and executed (at the moment) on the EVM, the other hiding protocol permits many obfuscation on data, but any forensic investigator is able to analyze the whole picture and to understand perfectly.

It can be demonstrated that if Eth Blockchain do not be so complete to store on blockchain ANY function call with ALL the function parameters every time the blockchain is changed, you could be able to build truly anonymous eth transfer. But it does. Stores them.

So you need an off-chain path, i.e. the transaction must be sent to a smart contract interacting with a dedicated server, let’s say via http as example, which, after anonymization, can send funds somewhere interacting again with some smart contract from the web or similar paths. And the transactions record on that server have to be immediately erased. Something like it!